# AJAX Request from Console to PHP File No Longer Working

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

The issue I'm experiencing is that an AJAX request that I make manually (via console) that used to return data, is no longer doing so. Every time I run the code, it results in an `undefined`, compared to earlier in the day in which "real" User data was being returned. Below you can see the AJAX request that I make, and the PHP code that adds Agents to an array, and then returns them.

**AJAX Request**

```
var result;

$.ajax({
      url: 'http://example.com/wp-content/alphabetise-agents.php',
      type: 'POST',
      dataType: 'JSON',
      data: { },
      success: function(response){
        result = response;

      } // end of success response
    }); // end of AJAX
```

**alphabetise-agents.php**

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
  //Connect to DB
$dbConn = mysqli_connect('localhost','wordpress','{some password}','wordpress')
or die('Error connecting to MySQL server.');

$stmt1 = $dbConn->prepare("SELECT * FROM wp_wpl_users");
$stmt1->execute();
$result1 = $stmt1->get_result();

$agents = [];

while ( $row1 = $result1->fetch_assoc() ) {


  // **** version 2 - create the html as well ****
  $first_name = $row1['first_name'];

  $last_name = $row1['last_name'];
  $last_name_for_url = str_replace(' ', '', $last_name);

  $full_name_no_space = $first_name . $last_name_for_url;
  $full_name_space = $first_name . ' ' . $last_name;

  $about = $row1['about'];
  $team_name = $row1['company_name'];
  $id = $row1['id'];

  $the_agent['html'] = '<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-3"><div class="team-block"><a class="team-block-mobile" href="/properties/' . $full_name_no_space . '" class="view_properties"></a><img src="/wp-content/uploads/WPL/users/'. $id .'/profile.png" alt="'. $full_name_space .'" /><div class="team-caption team-caption-before"><div class="team-caption-inner"><h4 class="team-name">'. $full_name_space .'</h4><p class="team-designation">'. $team_name .'</p></div></div><div class="team-caption team-caption-after"><div class="team-caption-inner"><h4 class="team-name">'. $full_name_space .'</h4><p class="team-designation">'. $team_name .'</p><p class="team-description">'. $about .'</p></div></div></div></div>';


  array_push($agents, $the_agent);


}

 $return_arr[] = array("users" => $agents);

 echo json_encode($return_arr);
```

Looking at the Network Tab suggests that the status is 200.

Could Wordpress perhaps have some AJAX limit that I hit? Also, something I've noticed is that changing the `mysqli_connect` settings to try and force an error (with incorrect username/password) does not actually provide an error in the console (when I first started working on this, I recall getting `connection refused` errors.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Edit: Some example HTML that was returned to me earlier in the day when it was working:

```
<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-3"><div class="team-block"><a class="team-block-mobile" href="/properties/Ivan" class="view_properties"></a><img src="/wp-content/uploads/WPL/users/17/profile.png" alt="Ivan Rickard Liow" /><div class="team-caption team-caption-before"><div class="team-caption-inner"><h4 class="team-name">Ivan</h4><p class="team-designation">Red Sevens</p></div></div><div class="team-caption team-caption-after"><div class="team-caption-inner"><h4 class="team-name">Ivan</h4><p class="team-designation">Red Sevens</p><p class="team-description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. </p></div></div></div></div>
```

Comment: Are you positive your query is actually returning results? Try changing your ajax data type to 'text' and see what comes out.

Comment: hi @Difster. I just changed it to "text" and it's an empty string. To re-iterate, I was 100% getting data returned before.

Comment: If it's returning an empty string you have a problem on the php side. Check your log for errors. You may very well just not be getting query results so there's nothing for the array to act on.

Comment: @Difster So after looking at the logs, it turns out that the $about variable is constantly being "undefined", despite this field being filled out for all Users (https://snag.gy/cyYFoV.jpg). 

Not entirely sure what to do now since the field is filled out, yet is being returned as undefined and breaking the entire thing.